# EJB 3.1 - Handling exceptions in asychronous jobs

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I have several asynchronous jobs that I would like to transparently handle the exception for.  I'd like to put the exception handling logic in another component / class.  With Seam 2, I extended an exception handler class.

For instance, I'd like to raise an event with the exception in it so that I can have several components act on it as they see fit.  The most common one is one that notifies administrators.

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: Why not use the CustomExceptionHandler? Just tested it, it can also catch Exceptions thrown in an @Asynchronous method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from [Part Three: New Features in EJB 3.1](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321142/Part-Three-New-Features-in-EJB-31) that you can probably adapt:

> #### Asynchronous Invocation of Session Beans
>
> Asynchronous processing is a
>   surprisingly common requirement for
>   many enterprise applications. Some of
>   the most obvious use cases are
>   triggering fire-and-forget background
>   processes, handling long-running tasks
>   while keeping the user interface
>   receptive or simply increasing
>   application throughput by utilizing
>   the benefits of parallel processing.
>   The easiest way of implementing
>   asynchronous processing in Java EE
>   applications today is using Message
>   Driven Beans. In fact, the first
>   Message Driven Bean example in EJB 3
>   in Action is used to implement
>   asynchronous order billing. More
>   precisely, a Message Driven Bean
>   (`OrderBillingMDB`) asynchronously
>   bills the customer after the order is
>   confirmed and updates the order
>   information with the results of the
>   billing attempt once it is completed.
>   Figure 1 shows this scenario:
>
> [image]
>
> Figure 1: Asynchronous order billing
>
> While using Message Driven Beans for
>   asynchronous processing certainly
>   works, it also forces you to deal with
>   messaging and JMS, even for relatively
>   lightweight functionality. This is
>   precisely the problem asynchronous
>   session bean invocation is designed to
>   solve. With this enhancement, you can
>   do asynchronous processing simply by
>   annotating a session bean method with
>   the `@Asynchronous` annotation. Let's
>   take a look at the re-factored EJB 3
>   in Action example for asynchronous
>   billing using the feature:
>
> ```
> @Stateless
> public class OrderBillingServiceBean implements OrderBillingService {
>     ...
>
>     @Asynchronous
>     public void billOrder(Order order) {
>         try {
>             // Attempt to charge the order.
>             bill(order);
>             // Send email notification of billing success.
>             notifyBillingSuccess(order);
>             order.setStatus(OrderStatus.COMPLETE);
>         } catch (BillingException be) {
>             // Send email notification of billing failure.
>             notifyBillingFailure(be, order);
>             order.setStatus(OrderStatus.BILLING_FAILED);
>         } finally {
>             update(order);
>         }
>     }
>
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> Because of the `@Asynchronous`
>   annotation, when the client invokes
>   the `OrderBillingService.billOrder`
>   method, the call will return
>   immediately instead of blocking until
>   the `billOrder` method finishes
>   executing. The EJB container will make
>   sure the method gets executed
>   asynchronously (probably using
>   messaging under the hood). As you can
>   see, the return type of the
>   asynchronous method is void. This will
>   probably be the case for a vast
>   majority of asynchronous Session bean
>   methods. However, EJB 3.1 can also
>   support a return type of
>   `java.util.concurrent.Future<V>`,
>   where `V` represents the resultant
>   value of an asynchronous invocation.
>   In case you are unfamiliar with it,
>   the `Future<V>` interface allows you
>   to do things like cancelling an
>   asynchronous invocation, checking if
>   an invocation is complete, check for
>   exceptions and getting the results of
>   an asynchronous invocation. Check out
>   the documentation for the `Future<V>`
>   interface here:
>   http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html.
>   Let's take a quick look at an example
>   using the Future return type. In
>   the `billOrder` method in the previous
>   example, we set the status of the
>   order according to the outcome of the
>   billing attempt and updated the order.
>   Let's assume that the invoker updates
>   the order themselves and wants to know
>   what the status of the billing attempt
>   was. We could do this by refactoring
>   the `billOrder` method as follows:
>
> ```
> @Stateless
> public class OrderBillingServiceBean implements OrderBillingService {
>     ...
>
>     @Asynchronous
>     public Future<OrderStatus> billOrder(Order order) {
>         try {
>             // Attempt to charge the order.
>             bill(order);
>             // Send email notification of billing success.
>             notifyBillingSuccess(order);
>             return new AsyncResult<OrderStatus>(OrderStatus.COMPLETE);
>         } catch (BillingException be) {
>             // Send email notification of billing failure.
>             notifyBillingFailure(be, order);
>             return new AsyncResult<OrderStatus>
>                 (OrderStatus.BILLING_FAILED);
>         }
>     }
>
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> The `javax.ejb.AsyncResult<V>` object
>   is a convenience implementation of the
>   `Future<V>` interface. It takes the
>   result of the asynchronous invocation
>   as a constructor argument. There's
>   nothing stopping you from using your
>   own implementation of `Future<V>`
>   however. Asynchronous invocation
>   supports a few other neat features
>   like delivery guarantees and
>   transacted send semantics. For
>   details, check out the spec draft.

If you have a specific problem, please ask a more specific question :)

#### See also

- [EJB 3.1 - A Significant Step Towards Maturity](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363578/EJB-31-A-Significant-Step-Towards-Maturity)
- The [`Future<V>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) Interface

Comment: I don't want to always do my exception handling in a try catch.  I'd like to have an interceptor / handler that handles that.  I guess I would write an EJB interceptor in that case?

Comment: You could also write a CDI/Weld interceptor, which is then usable for all your beans, not only EJBs. As i think about it, maybe it could even make the (not-really-beautiful)CustomExceptionHandler superfluous.

Comment: That's what I will have to do, I didn't know if there already was an application exception handler that I could just override like in Seam.