# How to avoid exception catch block on @Asynchronous ejb method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb-3.1

Assume that we got an remote ejb which provides a asynchronous method with exception

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    ...

       @Asynchronous
       public Future<Void> doSomething()
       throws MyException
       {
             //implementation
       }

    ...
}
```

Now the client side:

```
 try {
       Future<Void> result = myBean.doSomething()
 }
 catch(MyException e)
 {
       //Useless required catch block?
 }
```

I know that the exception can be retrieved of the Future object when it is returned.

My question is if there is a better implementation without that useless empty catch block which will not be called anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if you throw your custom exception, then you decided that the calling code has to deal with it and you do so by catching it as with any synchronous method. And if you are saying, the catch block is useless, then the question is, why you throw the exception at all?

To avoid dealing with the exception in the client code, you may instead return an object holding the outcome of the call, which can then be an error that occurred. You still need to handle this situation, but you won't need a try-catch-block. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348700/ejb-3-1-handling-exceptions-in-asychronous-jobs) for an example.

Further reading: [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html).

Comment: Yes, i meant Future, replaced that in the code.

But the Exception on call will not be thrown but must be catched, the block is really annoying.

Comment: @SeeM: Ok, I understand - I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution will be to make MyException to extend RunTimeException like this. Not sure if this is possible for you. Notice the annotaiton with rollback=false (Assuming you have a checked exception without rollback set to true). This way you don't have to mention it in the throws clause or catch it. The annotation will make sure that it will not be wrapped in EJBException.

```
@ApplicationException(rollback = false)
public class MyExcepton extends RuntimeException {

...
}
```